# Waze deep link in IOS, make "Open with Waze" to open my app

Tags: ios, iphone, whatsapp, waze

Deep link in IOS, make "Open with Waze" to open my app

So we added a deep link on our iOS app , and it is working well and opens waze on the location we want

But now when I have address sent on whatsapp and I am selecting the option to open it with Waze it opens my app instead of waze 
See screenshot:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/lxgjcu3pn6e0anm/2019-01-09%2010.02.44.png?dl=0

```
enter code here

if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL 
URLWithString:@"waze://"]])
{
NSString *urlStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://waze.com/ul? 
ll=%f,%f&navigate=yes", lat, lon];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlStr]];
}
else
{
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL 
URLWithString:@"http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/id323229106"]];
}



enter code here
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
    <array>
        <string>waze</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</array>
```

Comment: Please note that this is not Deep linking. You are trying to an app from your app. Your have implement URL Schemes in your plist to support this feature. For more details https://www.appcoda.com/working-url-schemes-ios/

Comment: Hi,

We have already implemented it using the plist.info and using the schema as per the link explains, you can see code below of plist.info file that is specific for waze linking.
`code`
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
 <array>
  <dict>
   <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
   <array>
    <string>waze</string>
    <string>com.googleusercontent.apps.553651920107-d604f1ip9g306h90i4imvck0n83cjmgt</string>
   </array>
  </dict>
 </array> 
`code`

Comment: and you can see screenshot below 

https://www.dropbox.com/s/vem2z10bl4k97ro/2019-01-13_22-11-25.png?dl=0

and if you want to look complete plist.info file you can see below plist file code

https://www.dropbox.com/s/50o7w5qewd9np83/Info.plist?dl=0

Please suggest what we are missing with this.

Answer (score 0):

because you're adding

```
<key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
    <array>
        <string>waze</string>
```

you're basically saying that your app will "listen" for the waze wakeup call. ie. when some other app tries to open waze, your app could be called upon instead. 
If you take  `<string>waze</string>` out of your plist file, this side effect should not occur.

Funny thing is one could steal the deeplinks from other apps ... hmm... interesting. ;)